# Firefox problems when remapping Copy to ctrl-c

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I remapped Copy to ctrl-c via Preference>Keyboard>Shortcuts and it works pretty good. But when I have the find dialog open in Firefox, when I try and Copy I actually end up toggling "Match Case". I don't care if I have a shortcut for "Match Case", could someone please help me keep my Copy functionality while the Find dialog is open?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) (or some similar shortcut remapping program for Mac) to remap Control C to Command C. This will prevent Firefox from knowing that you pressed Control C at all, and thus it won't enable the "Match Case" option in the find dialog box.

Alternatively if you are interested you can read up the documentation on [Karabiner Element's](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) new [complex modifications feature](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html) to remap Control C to Command C in Firefox. This is similar to doing it with any other program, although I suspect that it is more reliable. However, it requires a bit more knowledge of how to add modifications to Karabiner Elements, because (as of writing this answer) the feature is quite new to Karabiner Elements, and there is no GUI method of creating complex modifications (apart from importing one from the website, but you might not find the one you are looking for).

Comment: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#emulation-modes Right now I'm using a few of the items from this, this is _very_promising. Let me trial this at work this upcoming week! (I'm a linux user with a new dev job using a mac hehe). Thank you!